# Unable to import PIL.Image for qrcode

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I run into this weird error, I need to use `qrcode` with `pillow`, so I did `pip install pillow qrcode` (after initiating the virtual environment). Then, the following thing happens

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> Image
<module 'PIL.Image' from '/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.pyc'>
>>> import qrcode;
>>> qrcode.make("1").show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qrcode/main.py", line 8, in make
    return qr.make_image()
  File "/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qrcode/main.py", line 186, in   make_image
    from qrcode.image.pil import PilImage
  File "/vagrant/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/qrcode/image/pil.py", line 5, in   <module>
    import Image
ImportError: No module named Image
```

`from PIL import Image` works but `qrcode` doesn't work. Not sure what is going on

Answer (score -2):

install PIL on Ubuntu:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/156484/how-do-i-install-python-imaging-library-pil

header for your program, code:

```
##some magic for 3rd party packages
import site
site.main()
##headers
from PIL import Image
##programm
#here your program!!!
```

--
Your friend!!!